# handling href when importing separate standalone latex documents and assembling them into one document

Tags: hyperref, standalone, import

This is a follow up on the question

[How to import separate standalone latex documents and assemble into one document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94822/how-to-import-separate-standalone-latex-documents-and-assemble-into-one-document)

I am using the package `standalone` to assemble many child latex files from different folders in the tree into one parent file at the top level while keeping each child in its own folder and be able to build each child document as separate latex document.

Using the above package, with the package `import` is working well. But there is one big problem when using links.

When using `href` in a child document to link to a file relative to it (say in the same folder), then when building the parent document, the links do not work since the path in the link is now not valid. i.e. hyperlinks do not get adjusted for the level the parent document is in.

Here is a picture of the set up with 2 small files as a complete example

```
main.tex   (now the link below is wrong when main document is build)
  |
  |
  A/----+ child.tex  (this contains href to foo.pdf)
          foo.pdf
```

main.tex is

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\subimport*{A/}{child}%
\end{document}
```

and child.tex is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{foo.pdf}{my pdf file}
\end{document}
```

One solution is to use absolute path in the links. But this is a problem since I can move the tree itself to different location and the absolute path can change. Another option is to use a path in the child file that is already adjusted taking into account the parent level. So in this example I would write in the child.tex this

```
 \href{A/foo.pdf}{my pdf file}
```

instead of

```
 \href{foo.pdf}{my pdf file}
```

But now the links when I build the child document only will be wrong.

Also this means if I change the internals of the tree layout, (say move the folder A one level down) the links will all have to be fixed manually.

**I'd like to find if there is a better and automated way to handle this?**

The import package handles the relative path for the import fine, but I need something to handle the `href` links as well used in the document.

Or may be I should just give up on the idea of importing separate standalone latex documents and assembling then into one document because if the href links are broken, then this whole thing will not work. I have many links that I use that are relative to the document level. May be Latex is not right for such a task.

**Update 1**

I found a big problem with the [`currfile` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/currfile) but I have not yet looked to see if there is an option to handle this case.  Given this tree, same as above, except I just renamed the files:

```
index.tex   
  |
  |
  A/----+ index.tex  (this contains href to foo.pdf)
          foo.pdf
```

Notice that I used the same file name (index.tex) which is very common for the above level and the lower level.

Now `currfiledir` does not work. It gets confused by the same name and does not handle the link correctly. When I change the name to `index2.tex` for the child, then it worked. i.e. the same exact files as I have shown above, just renamed them to `index.tex` *in both fodlers*  caused this problem !

I used `index.tex` all over the place. In each folder, I have `index.tex`. I suppose I can rename each file to be unique. But I hope there is an option in this package to handle this.

Here are the files for completion based on the above tree:

index.tex (in the top level)

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{currfile}

\begin{document}        
\subimport*{A/}{index}  %renaming this from index1 will make it work!
\end{document}
```

index.tex (in the lower level, the child)  %rename to index1.tex to make it work!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{currfile}
\begin{document}
\href{\currfiledir foo.pdf}{my pdf file}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for some reason you prefer not to use the `currfile` package (eg you only have a version strictly earlier than `v0.7b` and are using the `import` package with files in different directories with the same name), here's a possible alternative solution, relying just on the `import` package.

The idea is to use the `\import@path` macro when it is available, i.e. because the `import` package is loaded, and that should keep track of the path for us. When it is not available, it is because the sub-document is being compiled directly (not through `import`) and so we should use a blank path prefix in that case. We wrap everything up in a user macro `\currentimportpath`.

1. `main.tex`:

   ```
   \documentclass[titlepage]{article}%
   \usepackage{standalone}
   \usepackage{import}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \makeatletter
   \providecommand{\currentimportpath}{\import@path}
   \makeatother
   \begin{document}
   \subimport*{A/}{main}%
   \end{document}
   ```
2. `A/main.tex`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \providecommand{\currentimportpath}{}% for when this file is compiled directly
   \begin{document}
   \href{\currentimportpath foo.pdf}{my pdf file}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: excellent!  It worked. I found that I can just use `\providecommand{\currentimportpath}{\import@path}` in both the parent and the child just the same and will work even when I build the child on its own. This is good, since in my tree, it is many levels, and a file can be both a child and a parent at the same time, so I need to be able to build at any level without changing things. Thanks again for your help. I also sent an email about the problem with `currfiledir` to the author of the package as you suggested.

Comment: Note that this issue with `currfile` is created by the changes done by `import`. Filename with the same name in different directories are supported in general.

Comment: @cyberSingularity: I'm working on a fix for `currfile`, but still have to find the time to analyse the issue and the `import` source code.

Comment: @cyberSingularity: I just uploaded v0.7b of `currfile` which supports `\subinput*` and similar macros from `import`. It turned out that they need a different file path search order to work. I'm in email contact with the OP and informed him already.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Fantastic. Thanks for that. I have edited my posts slightly to refer to the new version, and deleted previous comments.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `currfile` package (already loaded by `standalone`):

1. `main.tex`:

   (just add `\usepackage{currfile}` to make it explicit, and in case you ever remove `standalone`)

   ```
   \documentclass[titlepage]{article}%
   \usepackage{standalone}
   \usepackage{import}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{currfile}
   \begin{document}
   \subimport*{A/}{child}%
   \end{document}
   ```
2. `A/child.tex`

   add `\usepackage{currfile}` and prefix `\currfiledir` to each `\href`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{currfile}
   \begin{document}
   \href{\currfiledir foo.pdf}{my pdf file}
   \end{document}
   ```

Note the space after `\currfiledir`, and lack of slash:

- When compiling `child.tex` directly, `\currfiledir` is empty (so you don't want a slash).
- When compiling `child.tex` through `main.tex`, `\currfiledir` is `A/` (so the slash is already there).

You could of course write your own `\myhref` to automatically prefix `\currfiledir`, eg

```
\newcommand*{\myhref}[1]{\href{\currfiledir #1}}
```

and then invoke as

```
\myhref{foo.pdf}{my pdf file}
```

(Note that if you are using the `import` package with files in subdirectories having the same name as the main file, then you need `currfile` version `0.7b` or newer for this solution to work.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know about this package. I just tried it on the above example, and it does worked very well.

Comment: Well, I have some bad news. I found a big problem in this package when I started to use it on my actual tree. Easier to explain with diagram. I'll add an update above. I need to also research this more to see if there is an option to avoid this.